# Anchor tags for local pages don't follow through in SvelteKit application

Tags: javascript, html, sveltekit, editorjs

EDIT: Interestingly, if I insert a broken `href`, I do get a *page not found* error. But if it's a correct one, nothing happens.

I have an rich text field made with *EditorJS*. The user should be allowed to link to other files in the same library. So I got an inline-tool that allows to create links like `<a href="/library/other-file">Other File</a>`. Unfortunately, clicking these links in the EditorJS field does not actually forward the user to the *Other File*. However, when I inspect the element and just click the `href` there, it does open the respective page.

I'm using SvelteKit for routing and the same linking logic seems to work in other parts of the application (sometimes I also just change the window.location to the new route).

To be honest, I'm somewhat lost. I'm not even sure if the reason is coming from some mistreatment of SvelteKits oder EditorJS' logic, or if I overlook something more fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor probably uses `contentEditable` and any links within a editable section will not trigger on click. You could probably work around this, by adding a manual click event listener like this:

```js
link.addEventListener('click',
  () => document.location.href = link.href
);
```

If the link is currently not editable, there might be other logic which prevents the default behavior for some reason. The same workaround should apply.

Comment: I will look into this, thanks! I tried adding `<a href="..." contentEditable="false">` but that didn't seem to have any impact. Would this be comparable in expected outcome?

Comment: @MichaBrugger Creating a non-editable island should also work, though if set via HTML attribute, the casing should be `contenteditable` (the DOM property is camelCased).

Comment: `contenteditable` didn't change anything (even with the right casing). But adding an eventListener worked like a charm! Thanks for your quick help, appreciate it!